# Calling checkbox only if checked

Tags: javascript, forms, math, checkbox

i have a checkbox that toggled with a button
but i also need to add the its value to an equation, ONLY IF its checked.
what i got right now is this, but it just add regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=javascript>
function validate(chk){
  if (chk.checked == 1)
    chk.checked = 0;
  else
    chk.checked = 1; 
}
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="ghj" id="ghj" value="100000">testing sheep<br>
<input type="button" class="button-primary widget-control-save" name="Check_All" value="Check All" onmouseout="compute(this.form)" onClick="validate(ghj)">
<input type="text" id="rslt" name="rslt">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- hide this script from old browsers
function compute(form)
{
var test = parseInt(document.getElementById('ghj').value, 10) || 0;
f = (test + 10);

document.getElementById('rslt').value = f;
}

// done hiding from old browsers -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

if...else statements may work but if i have a longer form that would mean hundreds of possibilities, and i'd like a more efficient way..

Comment: sorry if its a little confusing i didnt know how to explain otherwise

Comment: Are you trying to check whether the checkbox is checked when clicking the 'Check All' button and add some value to the equation?

Comment: yup thats it add the value only if the checkbox is checked. oh and it will be a long form so if..else probably wont be too efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute only the checkbox which are checked. Then do something like this

```
function compute(frm){
    var test = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++){
        if(frm.elements[i].type == 'checkbox'){
            if(frm.elements[i].checked){ //Do something if checkbox is checked
                test += parseInt(frm.elements[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('rslt').value = test;
```

}

See sample code [jsfiddle.net/5u5TH](http://jsfiddle.net/5u5TH/)

Comment: thanks a lot! and thanks for putting up the fiddle too.. it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little while to figure out what you're asking but I think you want to do something like this:

```
function compute(form)
{
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('ghj');
  if(checkbox.checked) {
    var test = parseInt(checkbox.value, 10) || 0;
    f = (test + 10);
    document.getElementById('rslt').value = f;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes but what if i have a long form? then there would be hundreds of possibilities!

Comment: Are you trying to solve a specific problem or are you just tinkering around? I'm having trouble imagining what the purpose of this could be, let alone a longer version of this with hundreds of possibilities. What sorts of possibilities?

Comment: ok so i`m  creating a "build your own plan" feature in which the user can click "Add" on each option and this will set off the checkbox with a value that will then be later used to generate a query string. meanwhile setting the checkbox off also updates the total amount that the customer has to pay if he adds that option using the compute function above. The query string generated is passed on to a form in which the customer fills out personal details and sends his custom plan (in hidden fields) along with the rest of the info.